# Почему этот код, написанный на TypeScript отрабатывает нормально?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Я наткнулся на код в интернете, написанный на TypeScript. Вот он:

```js
type Selector<T, R> = (item: T, index: number) => R;

function groupBy<T, TKey, TValue>(source: T[], keySelector: Selector<T, TKey>, valueSelector: Selector<T, TValue>) {
  const result = new Map();
  for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    const item = source[i];
    const key = keySelector(item, i);
    const value = valueSelector(item, i);
    if (!result.has(key)) {
      result.set(key, []);
    }
    result.get(key).push(value);
  }

  return result;
}

const q1: Map<number, number[]> = groupBy([1, 2, 3, 4], x => x % 2, x => x + 1);
const q2: Map<boolean, {x: string, i: number}[]>  = groupBy(["aaa", "bbb", "cc", "q", "lalaka"], (_, i) => i%2 === 0, (x, i) => ({i, x}))
console.log(q1, q2);
```

Как человек, изучающий TS я хочу понять его. Он отрабатывает нормально, но в этом и вопрос. Почему он нормально работает? Мой вопрос вызвал второй аргумент функции groupBy. Это колбек функция, которая типизируется типом Selector. Selector - это искусственно созданный тип, который представляет функцию, принимающую два параметра. Тогда вопрос: почему не генерируется ошибка, когда мы вызываем функцию groupBy в первый раз, передав вторым параметром функцию вида x => x % 2? Мы ведь сказали, что у этой функции тип Selector, который является функцией с двумя параметрами, а передаём мы только один x. Вот другой пример с этого же сайта, который намного проще:

```js
function baz(a: string, b: boolean) {
    return 10;
}

const f3: (a: string) => number = baz; /* Error:
Type '(a: string, b: boolean) => void' is not assignable to type '(a: string) => void'.
*/
```

Здесь понятно, что переменная f3 типизируется функцией с одним параметром, поэтому baz сюда уже не подойдёт. Так почему же всё-таки первый пример тогда работает? Что я упускаю? Объясните пожалуйста желательно по подробней.

По поводу примеров с методами массивов. Я понимаю, почему мы можем передавать 1 параметр а не все 3. JS позволяет передавать в функцию сколько угодно параметров, делая лишние underfined. Но тут - то TS. Разве сигнатура в типе Selector это не своего рода контракт на то, что все функции принимающие этот тип должны выглядеть именно так? Я бы ещё понял, если бы параметр index был опционален т.е. (index?: number). А если мне например нужно будет сделать так, чтобы эта колбек функция обязательно принимала 2 параметра? Как быть тогда?

Comment: Во втором сделайте наоборот: в baz один аргумент и в f3 два аргумента - и это заработает аналогично первому примеру

Comment: О том, как и почему обрабатывается количество аргументов, написано тут https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters-in-callbacks

Comment: «...мы можем передавать 1 параметр а не все 3» — но у вас ведь ситуация вообще не такая. В первом коде передаётся 2 параметра в функцию, которая принимает 1 параметр — нет никаких причин, почему TypeScript должен это запрещать

Answer (score -2):

Внутри своего вопроса вы уже ответил на свой же вопрос :)

### Первый фрагмент кода

В первом примере кода, `valueSelector` и `keySelector` являются **callback** функциями, точно также как и при работе, например с методами массива.

Внутри самой функции `groupBy` все требования к колбекам выполняются, то есть подставляется элемент и его индекс.

Если также остались вопросы, то приведу пример на методах массива. Возьму метод `filter`. Описанный тип для этого метода выглядит следующим образом:

```
filter(predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): T[];
```

Но использовать его можно так:

```
[].filter(v => Boolean(v))
```

И так:

```
[].filter((_, i) => i === 2)
```

И даже так:

```
[].filter((_, i, arr) => arr[i] === 3 && i === 2)
```

По аналогии с этим методом работают и другие методы массивов.

Тип описан для того, чтобы понимать какие аргументы можно принять из callback функции.

### Второй фрагмент кода

В данном случае используется описание функции и последующий ее вызов.

Именно поэтому все аргументы вызываемой функции должны соответствовать описанному типу

Comment: Во втором фрагменте `f3` тоже принципиально ничем не отличается от callback-функций из первого фрагмента

Comment: @andreymal Простите, что? Во втором примере просто описан тип переменной и к ней присваивается другая функция, которая имеет другой тип. Это не разу не callback

Comment: Переменная, которая ссылается на функцию — это и есть самый настоящий callback

Comment: Я просто оставлю это тут - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

Comment: Это не отменяет того факта, что оба фрагмента используют переменные, ссылающиеся на функции, и между этими фрагментами нет никакой принципиальной или технической разницы. Ваше утверждение « все аргументы вызываемой функции должны соответствовать описанному типу» является **неверным** — в комментарии к вопросу я уже привёл пример, как переделать второй фрагмент так, чтобы он заработал даже без такого соответствия.

Comment: Я за вас очень рад, правда. Напишите тогда свой ответ на вопрос и все, если я прям так сильно не прав, как вы выразились, то ответ просто "заминусуют" и все.

Comment: Ну ладно, раз вы не заинтересованы в исправлении неверности своего ответа, то я поставлю первый минус ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Спасибо за первый минус. Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, я не много дополнил вопрос, чтобы лучше вникнуть в эту тему.